# OCR Error Correction

Tags: ocr, post-processing, error-correction

I'm working on cleaning OCR-ed documents, working with an commercial OCR engine. The quality of its output is bad, as it often produces both undefinded characters text, and misspellings within the text due to the very noisy background.

Our first approach is apply some spelling-corretion with Regular Expression.
Our second approach is to create a library of error

|------------1--------------------------|--------2----------|--------3----------

---

|Image Segmentation of misspelled words |  Misspelled word  |   Human correction

---

|   Image segmentation of the word      |      clcar        |      clear

The idea of the second approach is similar to Google reCaptcha project. We will ask a lot of people to proofread the OCR-ed text. In order to to speed up this process only the misspelled words (recognised through a spelling-corrector) will be selected out. They will be given a image segmentation of the misspelled word in the pdf-file and have to correct it manually

However we don't know how can we map the misspelled word in the OCR-ed document back to the original PDF-File.

What are the best practices for this problem? Are there open-source implementations that do this sort of thing (OpenCv,Algorithm,...etc)?